# CSS or jQuery for this table-style layout

Tags: jquery, css-tables

Here's the code I've come up to layout my page.  The problem is, this is all statically defined.  What I would like is for this to be dynamic, i.e. changes sizes based on the size of the browser used for viewing.  I'm pretty sure that all of the divs can be fixed in size for a particular page dimension.  The Menu and Content panes should be the divs that adjust to fit.  The content div will be scrollable as necessary.

Can I do this with CSS or would jQuery be necessary - or is there a better approach altogether?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html, body  
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #container
        {
        }

        #toolbar
        {
            background-color: Gray;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #PageDescription
        {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: Purple;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #RestOfPage
        {
            position: absolute;    
            background-color: White;
            top: 82px;
            height: 905px;
            width: 1800px;
        }
        #Footer
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 987px;
            left: 0;
            background-color: Yellow;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
        }
        #LeftPane
        {
            position: inherit;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: Lime;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #RightPane
        {
            position: inherit;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: Silver;
            left: 120px;        
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <label for="Category">Category: </label><select id="Category"></select>
        </div>
        <div id="Footer"></div>
        <div id="PageDescription">
            <h1>Page Description</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="RestOfPage">
            <div id="LeftPane">Menu</div>
            <div id="RightPane">Content Content Content</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/QwAGV/](http://jsfiddle.net/QwAGV/) to play with.

Comment: You are positonning (almost) all (child of body) elements in absolute, this is a bad bad thing :( . Right now, your `<body>` element only contains the `#toolbar` element. Everything else is out of its context. You should redo all this template with relative positionning instead.

Answer (score 1):

Redo the template using relative positioning, float, clear, and percentages. Ideally, this is what each of your code snippets should have, using borrowed and edited code:

```
#LeftPane {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 13%;
    background-color: Lime;
    /* You should avoid using named colors, try 
     * #98ED00 or another hex value*/
    height: 100%;
}
#RightPane {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: Silver;
    height: 100%;
}
```

With this CSS, the page should rescale just fine. And for future reference, avoid `absolute`. It's inflexible, hard to move around, and every element will put its content right on top or underneath that styled element unless explicitly told NOT to do so. In short, it'll only look good on your computer.

Also, this solution can be fully implemented in CSS. No jQuery is necessary.

Here are some relevant links for you to reference in the future, courtesy of W3C Schools.

[CSS Positioning](http://w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), [CSS Floating](http://w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp), [CSS Box Model](http://w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: `absolute` is okay on elements within elements with `relative` positioning.

Comment: Other than that though it should certainly be avoided. Especially here because he doesn't have all his in a container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use percent based width and height with the #RestOfPage too. Look into using min-height/max-height in addition to the percent based layout.  That will stop things from rearranging unexpectedly.

Comment: I really need the LeftPane to be a fixed width with the RightPane resizing to fill.  I understand all the absolute stuff is bad, but I was just trying to get what the page should look like, not how it should be coded.  I made a lot of attempts using floats, and relative positioning, but always ran into a snag.